# Fastlane Cocoapods stored on Artifactory

Tags: cocoapods, artifactory, fastlane

Does Fastlane have integration with CocoaPod dependencies that are stored in Artifactory? If so, how do you connect Fastlane to Cocoapods in Artifactory?

Answer (score 3):

Fastlane is [using](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/cocoapods.rb) the Cocoapods client to resolve pods, so assuming you followed the [steps](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/CocoaPods+Repositories) describing how to use the Pod command line with Artifactory this should work out of the box.

Comment: I'm glad to know it works out of the box. Thank you for the response!